# Animations when scrolled not working - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a website where when you scroll, it goes "smoothly" (with animate scrolltop in jquery) to another section, denying you to scroll to another site. Now, what I want to do is that when you scroll to section2, the elements appear with some animations and when you left it, it disappears, and so on...

I did this but it only works when I refresh the page and I'm already in that section. In other case, it doesn't work. I think it doesnt work because when you call the $(window).scrollTop() it returns instantly the scrollTop, but it actually should wait 750ms for the scroll animation to finish. I tried to use setTimeOut and other things but I couldn't make it run.

Here is the code:

```
function animacionObjetosDeSections() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //each height of the sections
    var altoSection2 = $('#section2').offset().top;
    var altoSection3 = $('#section3').offset().top;

    //if scrolltop is the same to the height of section2, it displays the animation, else it returns to original state
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == altoSection2) {
        $('.view-of-page').animate({left: '2%'},600);
        $('.page-info h2').animate({opacity: 1}, 650);
    } else {
        $('.view-of-page').animate({left: '-50%'},600);
        $('.page-info h2').animate({opacity: 0}, 650);
    }
});
```

}

**EDIT:**

Know it works but for each scroll it recognizes like 30 scroll events and I have to wait those 30 events * 750ms to make the function work again.

CODE:

```
function animacionObjetosDeSections() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    //each height of the sections
    var altoSection2 = $('#section2').offset().top;
    var altoSection3 = $('#section3').offset().top;

    //if scrolltop is the same to the height of section2, it displays the animation, else it returns to original state
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == altoSection2) {
        alert("hola");
        $('#section2 .view-of-page').animate({left: '2%'},600);
        $('#section2 .page-info h2').animate({opacity: 1}, 650);
    } else {
        $('#section2 .view-of-page').animate({left: '-50%'},600);
        $('#section2 .page-info h2').animate({opacity: 0}, 650);
    }
        },701);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use `slideup()` and `slidedown()` functions when you reach to that section.
for example when you scroll to section2 use `slidedown()` function on your section div and it will appear with animation and when you leave that section make use of `slideup()`function and your section will disappear with animation.

Comment: But I want to slide horizontally and not vertically. And I think it wont work because of the same problem of delaying the time it gets the scrollTop()